# Symfony web server configuration

Tags: php, xampp, symfony-1.4

I follow the tutorial here http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine and after I went to this address said on the tutorial -->> `http://localhost:8080/index.ph` says: "Object not found". Also when I looked at the \web folder, it doesn't have `index.php`.

Is the `index.php` will generate after executing the `generate:project` command or what?
I'm using windows, xampp and symfony v1.4. Please I need help with this, I couldn't get to start since last week because of this. Thank you in advance and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok I solve my problem with the `index.php`. now my problem is how to configure my web server to gain access to the symfony_data/web/sf directory because the index page has no images.

Comment: I know it's not helpful but you should probably move your learning towards Symfony 2+ as it stopped being maintained as of November 2012.

Comment: I wanted to move also but I'm not creating a website but I will edit the open-source project called **OrangeHRM** (this was the task given to me) and OrangeHRM used v1.4 so I need to learn v1.4 :-).

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Makes sense then.

Comment: The part about configuring web server is very well covered by the Jobeet tutorial. You need to add and alias to your VirtualHost in Apache.

Comment: Anyone know what is this error? I need help with this `Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\response\sfWebResponse.class.php on line 409`. I'm using **xampp 1.8.3** and **symfony 1.4**.